# 'CSS shape' with image overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a triangle:

```
#tri{
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: right;
border-top: 25px solid red;
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

I want the whole triangle area to be a link, so I did:

```
<a href="...">
    <div id="tri">
    </div>
</a>
```

And I also want the area to "cut" a background image, so that rather than red, it's a triangular portion of an image.

I tried numerous things, but to be honest, I was just guessing - adding it to `#tri` as a background image, adding `img` to the `div` element, as you already know these didn't work.

I assume it's possible, but I haven't been able to find an example, tutorial, or similar demo.

Can anyone lend me a hand?

http://jsfiddle.net/XSgwv/

Comment: create fiddle for it .. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So do I, but I created one, link in post. (literal copy of code in post..)

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating an image of the triangle and inserting it like this:

```
<a href="...">
<img class="tri" src="some.jpg" alt="red triangle" >
</a>
```

You can create various classes to change the way the triangle is viewed.

so:

OR

```
<a href="...">
<img class="tri"   alt="red triangle"/>
</a>


.tri{
width: 0;
height: 0;
float: right;
border-top: 25px solid red;
border-left: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

Please see:
http://jsfiddle.net/yvytty/bwQJC/2/

I prefer to use classes than id's, just makes it easier when also using javascript and getting elementsById, just a habit I am in.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't just cut the image to begin with!

Comment: some code snippets : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/foGus  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dakFi

Answer (score 1):

you can use the HTML  element is used with  elements to define a image map.

```
<map name=a>
  <area shape=rect coords=25,25,75,75 href=#fail href="http://www.example.com">
</map>
<img usemap=#a src=image.png>
```

change the co-ordinates with your triangle coordinates ..

Comment: I can't use co-ordinates. It occurs multiple times in varying positions, depending on the size of other elements.