# How to Make a Triangle with Background Pattern in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, less, css-shapes

I am trying to make the following with CSS

[image]

Making a triangle with CSS is straightforward but I don't know how to give it a non-solid background.

Any suggestions?

edit: The background pattern is a PNG image.

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image?rq=1

Comment: Are you trying to make the background yourself WITHOUT the use of an image, with only CSS?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat : Have you succeeded?

Comment: @Notulysses I actually ended up hacking it with a PNG over top, since that fit the project better. I appreciate your assistance though!

Answer (score 3):

```
.triangle {
   width: 160px;
   height: 160px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 30%;
   left: 45%;
   clip: rect(auto, 180px, auto, 100px);
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }

 .triangle::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(206,219,233,1)), color-stop(17%,rgba(170,197,222,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(97,153,199,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(58,132,195,1)), color-stop(59%,rgba(65,154,214,1)), color-stop(71%,rgba(75,184,240,1)), color-stop(84%,rgba(58,139,194,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(38,85,139,1)));
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

[**Example with gradient**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeyfH)

If you want to use `png` image for your `background` then you should change this property to :

```
background:url('my_url_to_the_image');
```

[**Example with PNG**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxgjk)

Comment: The only issue with this solution is the vertical scrollbar will appear before the actual bottom edge of the triangle reaches the bottom edge of the viewport. It is because the `clip` just clips the div **visually** without actually eliminating the space of the clipped half.

Comment: @King King : [Is it better that way](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zskcL) ?

Comment: yes, only `overflow:hidden` can actually clip an element, in fact there is a solution using only `overflow:hidden` without bothering with `clip`, *web-tiki* also posted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image?rq=1 as a comment under the OP's question.

Comment: And I also made this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/frWnj/2/ right after you posted your answer (so I decided not to post it as an answer).