# CSS triangle with color and background-image

Tags: css, geometry, background-image, transparent

I made a page consisting of several sections with different background colors and a transparent background image with noise (transparent "PNG file"). At the top of each section I placed a triangular shaped `div` with the color of the section above. I would also like to add the noise image to the triangles but I can't figure out how.

I've tried the `border-image` attribute in "CSS" but that just erases the whole triangular shape for some reason..

I would be grateful if you could help me out. "[This](http://www.floriskoch.com)" is the site I'm working on.

Comment: [Hope it helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23246687/3444240)

Comment: I just edited my post for a solution specific to your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rotated pseudo element :

### Generic solution:

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/F3a6V/)**

*HTML:*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    width:70%;
    height:70%;
    background-image: url(/*Path to your image*/);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

### EDIT: Your use case

In your use case, you can consider just rotating `.arrow-down` by 45deg and set `overflow:hidden;` on the sections. (you also need to remove the existing borders on `.arrow-down` and give it desired dimensions)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't can quite get it to work yet. On each different triangle I've set a different background-color which should overlay the transparent background-image. But for some reason the color doesn't show or distorts the shape, depending on the CSS used. I've updated the [site](www.floriskoch.com)

Comment: @user3626010 I just took a tour on your website, it looks like you managed to implement the solution I provided, good job. Could you set this question as answered by upvoting/accepting this answer if it helped?

Comment: Well yes it seems to work now, thanks a lot! However I still don't understand why I need to use two separate divs (arrow-down and section-ico). If I delete one, the whole thing dissappears. Also, I would very much like to upvote you but I seem to need more 'reputation'.