# Create triangular div using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-shapes

[image]

I need to create two triangular divs as described in the above pic so that I can trigger a hover effect on both of these.

Comment: You can't with HTML, I believe. The best you can do is use SVG or canvas for this.

Comment: Okay. When you run into a specific issue doing that, having done research, post a question about the problem you're having.

Comment: Possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image