# Side to side clickable triangles with background images with CSS

Tags: html, css, canvas, background, css-shapes

I've been recently in need of implementing this kind of layout in the main page of an app.
The general idea is to have 2 triangles side by side, matching the exact height of a device, being clickable and easily identifyiable inside the code,
which are gonna be use to redirect the user to a specific kind of service on another page. It's supposed to be a mobile app.

The idea I had in mind is more or less similar to this one:

[Triangle shape with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image)

The main difference is though, that I havent been able to achieve a way to have these triangles occupying the whole screen space, as with the usage of DIV or Canvas as well as SVG, I've had a hard time figuring out a way to to this.

This is about the idea I had in mind:
https://timsaudiocorner.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/mac-vs-pc1.jpg

But it should be rectangular matching a mobile phone resolution, and should be able to divide precisely both triangles, so that one can apply onclicks and animations per triangle.

Any ideas?