# Creating a triangle with only CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'm developing a responsive web application, and need to create 2 separate content areas as follows,
[image: Reference Image]

So far, I tried,

```
border-right: 30px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 30px solid #4c4c4c; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
```

But, unfortunately couldn't create a triangle.

Is there any other way to create a triangle using CSS with the possibility to wrap content entirely within the div's besides using the border property?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on *Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Related : [CSS3 triangle shape with background image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/css3-triangle-shape-with-background-image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for triangles with  borders and a transparent cut in between (which none of the existing answers seem to address) and so here is an example. It's absolutely possible to achieve with but takes a lot of hacking around.

**Using CSS Transforms:**

The below snippet uses pseudo-elements and transforms to produce the triangles effect. The output is responsive but the usage of skew transforms mean that if the container's shape becomes a rectangle then the skew angles would need modification and more tweaking of the positioning attributes etc.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.div-1,
.div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div-1 {
  top: calc(-100% - 5px);
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}
.div-1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  top: calc(100% + 7px);
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.div-2 {
  top: 5px;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
.div-2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 7px);
  width: calc(100% - 7px);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  border: 1px solid;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* just for demo */
.container{
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
body{
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, aliceblue, mediumslateblue);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='div-1'></div>
  <div class='div-2'></div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Gradients:**

Another approach would be to use a couple of linear gradients as background images like in the below snippet. But there are plenty of drawbacks here too. (1) Gradients have very poor browser support at present. (2) Angular gradients tend to produce jagged lines which would need smoothing. (3) You had specifically mentioned 2 div elements in the image in question and I presume you want content within them, in which case that would need extra work.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, transparent calc(50% + 2px), black calc(50% + 2px), black calc(50% + 4px), transparent calc(50% + 4px)), linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent calc(50% + 2px), black calc(50% + 2px), black calc(50% + 4px), transparent calc(50% + 4px)) ;
    }
.container:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  left: 4px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
.container:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 6px);
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  top: 4px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
/* just for demo */
.container{
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover{
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
}
body{
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, aliceblue, mediumslateblue);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

All these lead me to my suggestion, which is, to **use SVG** for creating such shapes. They are easy to create using just `path` elements, easily maintainable and are responsive by nature.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
svg path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
}
/* just for demo */

.container {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover {
  height: 400px;
  width: 700px;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, aliceblue, mediumslateblue);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <path d='M4,2 L98,2 98,96 4,2z M2,4 L2,98 96,98 2,4z' vector-effect='non-scaling-stroke' />
  </svg>
</div>
```

> **Note:** With any of the approaches mentioned above (or those given in other answers), you cannot make the content to remain within the boundaries of those triangles. Text can be placed upon them but the text cannot be contained within those boundaries unless the CSS Shapes module's `shape-inside` property is fully implemented.

Comment: thank you so much. I used the 'shape-inside ' with a SVG triangle and it worked... :)

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped :) Please check the browser support for `shape-inside` and make sure it works in all browsers that you need to support.

Comment: Yes, i've check it just a few minutes ago. Since SVG adjusted itself, the 'shape-inside' too adjusted itself, and it worked in all of my devices.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just don't give width and height will make triangle.

```
.triangle1 {
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 30px solid #4c4c4c; 
   position: fixed;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4osytwqa/1/)**

As per your image here i have created two reverse triangle.

```css
.triangle1 {
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid #4c4c4c; 
    position: fixed;
}
.triangle2 {
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid #4c4c4c; 
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle1">
</div>

<div class="triangle2">
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Here is one way you can add text inside triangle.

Add another text div inside triangle and set it's position.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4osytwqa/3/)**

Comment: thanks, i was able to create triangles, but still I couldn't insert content in it and the content appears directly above the triangles. Is there any way I could wrap the content to lie entirely within the div's ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.triangle1 {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-right: 200px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 150px solid black;
}
```

For DIV Element 1. For the second just make a square and render the triangle on the top of the square.

Answer (score 1):

> **Html code :**

```
<div id="DIV-Element1"></div>
<div id="DIV-Element2"></div>
```

> **Css :**

```
#DIV-Element1 { width: 0; height: 0; border-bottom: 100px solid black; border-right: 100px solid transparent; }
#DIV-Element2 { width: 0; height: 0; margin-left: 15px;border-top: 100px solid black; border-left: 100px solid transparent; }
```

> you can adjust your triangle by changing border

**I hope this will work**