# How to make a one cover image in HTML using a two image partition with diagonal

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, bootstrap-4

[image]

Hello I want to make a cover page using two images with partition looking as one right angle triangle and another is left angle triangel with diagonal how can i make it with HTML Code and Responsive too.

Here an image shows the mockup design related to my question  which i want to make exactly as per image.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. To the casual reader, it sounds like you can just make one rectangular image file that has a diagonal line. So can you explain what effect you're trying to achieve, and/or what kinds of problems you run into. For example, the [html5-canvas] tag sounds like you want to draw it in JavaScript rather than load it as an external resource, but the question body doesn't mention that at all.

Comment: Actually the image is a rough mockup so i want to make a design of cover page exactly as per mockup design thats it. i have clear define of image-1 and image - 2 where i want to put images and the design looks like one cover page with two image in diagonal view, @MrLister

Comment: Check this post. They are achieving this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/triangle-shape-with-background-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Triangle shape with background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969941/triangle-shape-with-background-image)